# Automatic Workflow activity not started

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a simple workflow **start-->createoredit-->automaticactivity-->End**. automatic activity doesnt do anything, i have default code in the script area of automati activity **FinishActivity "Automatic Activity Finished"** alone in the script area.

When i trigger the workflow, automatic activity is not started and performed, it is assigned to "NTAUTHORITY SYSTEM" with the state "Assigned" (In the Global Work List)

Whenever i restart the "Tridion Workflow Agent" service or whenever some other automatic activity assigned via workflow, automatic activity start performed.

I dont see any error message also in the event log.

Could anyone help me on this? I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

The first activity must always be a manual activity.  If you need to have the first activity automated then you need to rely on the event system for this.

EDIT:  I see you wrote the question to add the first activity to be manual.

When an automatic activity gets stuck in Assigned state, it usually means there is a script error.  There could also be something with the connectors between activities in your Visio design.  Check that everything us properly connected.  Try deleting the link between automaticactivity to End and recreating it again.

Comment: Hi Nickoli, i have added one manual activity as well as first activity, still the same problem occurs for me

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. It looks like your createoredit is the first activity and is manual.  Are you sure the event viewer doesn't show anything?  Can you please provide the code for your automatic activity?

Comment: FinishActivity "Automatic Activity Finished"

Comment: Please paste the code.  If the activity finishes, as per the log, but is still stuck, you may have an error after the FinishActivity statement.

Comment: FinishActivity "Automatic Activity Finished" this is the only line i have in my automatic activity script

Comment: Hmm... Try Call FinishActivity("Automatic Activity Finished")

Comment: FinishActivity("Automatic Activity Finished")  i have tried like this alos instead of FinishActivity "Automatic Activity Finished". However the situation remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the "Tridion Content Manager Workflow Agent" windows service is running. This fixed it for us.